# Use IOzone to check read/write performance of ext4 and btrfs?

Tags: filesystem, performance, ext4, btrfs

Can someone help me to use IOzone filesystem benchmark tool on Ubuntu to check the performance of ext4 and btrfs filesystems? I have installed Ubuntu into a VM.

Comment: take a look [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/05/iozone-examples/)

Comment: @minerz029 can you write a answer from the link?

Answer (score 0):

For example:

iozone -Rb spreadsheet_output_16M.xls -s 16G -r 16M

But please note that comparing ext4 to btrfs is comparing apples to oranges - btrfs does a lot more then what ext4 does (for example checking the checksum of read blocks to ensure validity) so I'd expect it to be slower then ext4.